# Jsoup - How can i get all links and titles in one array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, parsing, jsoup

this is my first question so far. I need to get links and titles from certain html page in one 2D Array. Here is my code:

```
public String[][] data;
descs = doc.select("a"); 
data= new String [spaceCount][2];
int count=0;
            for (Element e : descs ) {
                data[count][0]=descs.attr("href");
                data[count][1]=descs.attr("title");
                count++;
            } 
String svalues = data[0][0]+"\n"+data[0][1]+data[1][0]+"\n"+data[1][1];
output.setText(svalues);
```

But my problem is that it keeps getting the same data in every place. I mean that in every cell here is only one, same link and one, same title. I am newbie in java, but I think things in loop are not moving (and they should). Can anyone explain how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `Element e`. Change

```
           data[count][0]=descs.attr("href");
           data[count][1]=descs.attr("title");
```

to

```
           data[count][0]=e.attr("href");
           data[count][1]=e.attr("title");
```

and add as last line of the for loop:

```
if ( count == spaceCount )
   break;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now it gets links one by one as I wished, but it doesn't get title.

Comment: Then please show a piece of the html source with those links.

Comment: There is no need. Your solution is good, I needed to look into html code and it turned out that few first links just don't have title. Code is now working, thanks :).